# Problems with embedded forms in Symfony, how to make it with three table relationships?

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm trying to use an embedded form in Symfony 1.4 but i'm having problems with table relation ship. I have an User table, an UserPhone table, and a PhoneType table. UserPhone relates with PhoneType and User relates with UserPhone. How can i access a field from PhoneType?

Here's my current, non-working, piece of code:

```
$subForm = new sfForm();
$userPhoneType = new PhoneType();
$userPhoneType->UserPhone->User = $this->getObject();
$form = new PhoneTypeForm($userPhoneType);
$subForm->embedForm(1, $form);
$this->embedForm('phone_description', $subForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the form field like so, where "1" is the name of the embedded form key:

```
$form['phone_description'][1]['field_name']->render();
$form['phone_description'][1]['field_name']->renderLabel();
$form['phone_description'][1]['field_name']->getValue();
```